# elixir: command not found when installed through asdf

Tags: elixir, appveyor

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline with [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) for a [custom](https://github.com/springcomp/amqp-filter-exchange) [RabbitMQ Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html) written as an Erlang/OTP app. For this, I used [the Linux base image](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/linux-images-software/), but I must install a lot of dependencies.

The main problem is installing the correct version of [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html).

Even though I installed Elixir using [ASDF](https://asdf-vm.com/#/) and adjusted the `PATH` environment variable, the command is still not found during the build process.

Here is an [extract from the log](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/springcomp/amqp-filter-exchange/builds/23409483):

```
[00:00:04] mkdir ./sources
[00:00:04] git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ./sources/asdf --branch v0.4.3
[00:00:04] Cloning into './sources/asdf'...
[00:00:04] Note: checking out 'bcc959f6ef743d5362e5f08667fc8beb9dee07dc'.
[00:00:04] 
[00:00:04] You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
[00:00:04] changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
[00:00:04] state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
[00:00:04] 
[00:00:04] If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
[00:00:04] do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
[00:00:04] 
[00:00:04]   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
[00:00:04] 
[00:00:04] ./sources/asdf/bin/asdf plugin-add elixir
[00:00:04] initializing plugin repository...
[00:00:04] Cloning into '/home/appveyor/projects/amqp-filter-exchange/sources/asdf/repository'...
[00:00:05] Cloning into '/home/appveyor/projects/amqp-filter-exchange/sources/asdf/plugins/elixir'...
[00:00:05] ./sources/asdf/bin/asdf install elixir 1.6.6
[00:00:05] ==> Checking whether specified Elixir release/reference exists...
[00:00:06] ==> Downloading 1.6.6 to /tmp/elixir_build_kz98B0/elixir-precompiled-1.6.6.zip
[00:00:06]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[00:00:06]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
[00:00:06] 
[00:00:06]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
[00:00:06]  20 5071k   20 1055k    0     0  3758k      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01 3755k
[00:00:06] 100 5071k  100 5071k    0     0  16.2M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16.1M
[00:00:06] ==> Copying release into place
[00:00:07] ./sources/asdf/bin/asdf global elixir 1.6.6
[00:00:07] export PATH="$PATH:./sources/asdf/shims"
[00:00:07] which elixir
[00:00:07] ./sources/asdf/shims/elixir
[00:01:08] git clone https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-public-umbrella.git ./sources/rabbitmq-public-umbrella
[00:01:08] Cloning into './sources/rabbitmq-public-umbrella'...
[00:01:14] which elixir
[00:01:14] ./sources/asdf/shims/elixir
[00:01:17] make -C ./sources/rabbitmq-public-umbrella co
[00:01:17] make: Entering directory '/home/appveyor/projects/amqp-filter-exchange/sources/rabbitmq-public-umbrella'
[00:01:17]  DEP    rabbit_common
[00:01:18]  DEP    amqp_client
[00:01:19]  DEP    amqp10_common
[00:01:20]  DEP    amqp10_client
[00:02:19]  DEP    rabbitmq_shovel
[00:02:23]  DEP    rabbitmq_web_dispatch
            DEP    ... many rabbitmq dependencies ...
[00:02:24]  DEP    rabbitmq_web_mqtt
[00:02:24]  DEP    rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples
[00:02:25]  DEP    rabbitmq_web_stomp
[00:02:26]  DEP    rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples
[00:02:26]  DEP    rabbitmq_website
[00:02:30] make[1]: Entering directory '/home/appveyor/projects/amqp-filter-exchange/sources/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/deps/amqp_client'
[00:02:30] make[1]: elixir: Command not found
[00:02:30] make[2]: Entering directory '/home/appveyor/projects/amqp-filter-exchange/sources/rabbitmq-public-umbrella/deps/rabbit_common'
[00:02:30] make[2]: elixir: Command not found
```

Comment: asdf installs elixir in the home directory of the user. Is that correct?

Comment: You added a relative folder path to `$PATH`, this could be problematic. Does it work if you `export PATH="$PATH:/home/appveyor/projects/amqp-filter-exchange/sources/asdf/shims"`?